# JFormattedTextField Question

Tags: java, swing, input, format, jformattedtextfield

Hey guys,  I was wondering if there is anyway I can set a JFormattedTextField to have an auto format of an email input.  For example, When the user type an email address I want it to accept something like this:  jsmith1@smith.com

But I want it to always be like this   name@site.something(net,com,edu)

basically i always want the '@' and '.'

Answer (score 3):

I think your best bet is to subclass `AbstractFormatter` and use a regexp for email, something like:

```
public class EmailFormatter extends AbstractFormatter {
    @Override public Object stringToValue(String string) throws ParseException {
        Matcher matcher = regexp.matcher(string);
        if (matcher.matches())
            return string;
        throw new ParseException("Not an email", 0);
    }

    @Override public String valueToString(Object value) {
        return value;
    }

    final private Pattern regexp = Pattern.compile("EMAIL REGEXP TO FIND BY YOURSELF");
}

...
JFormattedTextField email = new JFormattedTextField(new EmailFormatter());
```

Note that I let you discover the right regexp for an email; you can the easy way, or if you prefer, check one RFC that describes a one-page long regexp that covers emails as per the real specs, but maybe you can simplify your requirements ;-)

Answer (score 0):

No easy way (that is, no such thing as JFormattedTextField.autoEmail()). But it wouldn't be hard to code something like this. In the field where the user presses a button or whatever to enter what's in the field, just don't accept the input if it doesn't have the @ and . characters. Either that or do a quick check to see if they included it, and if not, append it to the end.